# using groovy http-builder in preemptive mode

Tags: authentication, groovy, httpbuilder

When using groovy's http-builder with basic authentication the default behavior is to send an unauthenticated request first and resend the request with credentials after receiving a 401 in the first place. 
Apache's Httpclient offers [preemptive authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Preemptive_Authentication) to send the credentials directly on the first request. 
How can I use preemptive auth in Groovy's http-builder? Any code examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Based on a [JIRA issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Using-JIRA-REST-api-from-groovy/qaq-p/463463) you can do something like that :

```
def http = new RESTClient('http://awesomeUrl/')

http.client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) {
        httpRequest.addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + 'myUsername:myPassword'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
    }
})

def response = http.get(path: "aResource")

println response.data.text
```

Comment: beautiful.  I was getting errant (and seemingly harmless, but annoying) 500 errors with Spring Security Grails plugin and basic auth without preemptive mode set.  This fixed it.  Note I had to add the following imports:

import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest

Answer (score 41):

You can also solve it groovy style with

```
http = new RESTClient('http://awesomeUrl/')
http.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic '+"myUsername:myPassword".getBytes('iso-8859-1').encodeBase64()
```

Comment: Also, `getBytes('iso-8859-1')` can be replaced by simply `bytes`.

Comment: @tweber could you please clarify: what is the purpose of the encoding? is it somehow required by base64? or by the Basic auth protocol?

Edit: hmm, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243567/1083697) seems to address my question. Haven't wrapped my head around it yet though. Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Used following with Jenkins.

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def req = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
req.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)
def content = req.getInputStream().getText()
```