# getting 401-Unauthorized when I try to call a API

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am accessing an external Api call which requires an authorization token
my code looks like

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = "http://url/organizations/d5d6553e-6bb2-4081-87e2-353e80f47d6f/users.json";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

// Add an Accept header for JSON format.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic TFVBV0dkeFZlSklJZ0hjajM0M0I6");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
```

please let me know what to do

Comment: Please provide more information! Whats requirements to clients for this api? How should resulting request should look like?

Comment: If it is WCF then you can simple ask for the `wsdl` and generate the client for this api.

Comment: you can check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient . This may help .

Comment: Hi, this is some external api,I am not sure its WCF,what I need to access the data throught the API call with authentication token.I added the token(which is base 64 encoding) to header as given above.Is it the correct way to add ?