# Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient, apiary.io

I'm implementing an API made by other colleagues with Apiary.io, in a Windows Store app project.

They show this example of a method I have to implement:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://private-a8014-xxxxxx.apiary-mock.com/");

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient{ BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("user/list{?organizationId}"))
    {
        string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

In this and some other methods, I need to have a header with a token that I get before.

Here's an image of Postman (chrome extension) with the header I'm talking about:
[image]

How do I add that Authorization header to the request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: *Warning* For potential code searchers: this is an incorrect use of HttpClient!! Check https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ why.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

When using GetAsync with the HttpClient you can add the authorization headers like so:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

This does add the authorization header for the lifetime of the HttpClient so is useful if you are hitting one site where the authorization header doesn't change.

Here is an detailed SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: -1 because HttpClient must be reusable (see https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). If it must be reusable, setting the default request headers is a bad practice.

Comment: @JCKödel That's a false assumption you are making.  If you are always calling the same site with the same credentials for the lifetime of the HttpClient using the DefaultRequestHeaders saves you from having to continuously set them again with the same values.  You should re-read that article it talks about using the same instance of the HttpClient, it makes no statements about default request headers being bad practice.  If I am calling only one site ever with the HTTP client which in practice does happen using the DefaultRequestHeaders saves you from having to set them each time.

Comment: @JCKödel, though you are incorrect in your assumption, I upvoted your comment, because you brought up an important point. Added greater clarity to the answer.

Comment: @kmcnamee, what if I need to pass two tokens?

Answer (score 541):

A later answer, but because no one gave this solution...

If you do not want to set the header directly on the `HttpClient` instance by adding it to the `DefaultRequestHeaders` (to not send it to all the requests you will make with it), **you could set headers per request**.

But you will be obliged to use the `SendAsync()` method, the only method that takes a `HttpRequestMessage` instance in input (that allows configuring headers).

This is the right solution **if you want to reuse the `HttpClient`** -- which is a best practice for

- [performance and port exhaustion problems](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)
- doing something thread-safe
- not sending the same headers every time

Use it like this:

```
using (var requestMessage =
            new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://your.site.com"))
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", your_token);
    
    await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
}
```

Comment: Seems safer to not use DefaultRequestHeaders if the value changes frequently.

Comment: Note you very likely need `requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", your_token);` "Bearer" would be an invalid HTTP header

Comment: Everyone nowadays reuses the very same instance (as per the official recommendation), this one is the actual answer then.

Comment: -1 for not using `using`. ALL non managed resources MUST be disposed. It's not just about best practice, it's about not blowing up a server.

Other than that, that should be the accepted answer (see my comment on the accepted answer)

Comment: @JCKodel it would have added noise because you're not necessary obliged to use `using` but could instantiate in the constructor and dispose in the `Dispose()`

Comment: @JCKödel A link on how using HttpClient well (without `using`!) https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I never said use `using` on HttpClient (this is bad), I said on HttpRequesMessage (because it have unmanaged memory buffers for streaming that MUST be disposed after the use). The request and response are and must be disposed every request (otherwise you'll keep large memory chunks locked for a long time). The `HttpClient` is reusable, to an extend.

Comment: @JCKödel why is it bad to be `using` the `HttpClient`?

Comment: @JCKödel if you mean not `using` a `new HttpClient` for each request, I agree completely.  But is there a problem with `using` a client for multiple requests?

Comment: @Bondolin I think you misunderstood `using` was meaning using the keyword `using(){}` which dispose the instance....

Comment: No, that's precisely what I meant.  My understanding is that there is nothing wrong with `using` an `HttpClient`, doing a few requests, and then disposing of the client at the end of the `using` block.  I do not like the approach of a static client that never gets disposed.

Comment: The best is to have 1 httpClient for each api/server to query and keep it as long as possible. Which is most of the time incompatible with using `using`. Static could be good (at least better that multiple instances) but better is to use dependency injection. One instance kept all along the application lifetime is good.

Comment: This thread is another tribute to IDisposable as a failure of the language designers. You must not dispose HttpClient, but you must always dispose HttpRequestMessage. It's a recipe for disaster as developers must learn this one blown up server at a time.

Comment: @Skrymsli that's not entirely true. You should dispose of HttpClients after you don't need them anymore! It's just that, since you can reuse the same instance, you can keep it around for later use. On the other hand, disposing of the request object is a must because the object's value is scoped in nature. So basically if you dont dispose of it, you will start piling up request objects that have no use. In a simple app you might only have 1 single HttpClient (that you likely use until your application shuts down), but you more than likely will have many, many request obejcts.

Comment: @AsPas the request object is not the HttpClient and can be disposed independently. If something is IDisposable it should ALWAYS be disposed when no longer used. I should have said you must not rapidly create and dispose HttpClient, so maybe it's just HttpClient that is badly designed, but I still think IDisposable is a fail... good languages don't need it.

Answer (score 112):

The accepted answer works but can get complicated when you want to try adding Accept headers. This is what I ended up with. It seems simpler to me, so I think I'll stick with it in the future:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/*+xml;version=5.1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authstring);
```

Comment: But I call API one more time, that time I face error like Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values.

Comment: @akash-limbani If you're reusing the same client, check before trying add.  
```  

  if (!client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
{
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authstring);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes, you only need this code.

```
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);
```

Answer (score 8):

Following the greenhoorn's answer, you can use "Extensions" like this:

```
  public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static HttpClient AddTokenToHeader(this HttpClient cl, string token)
        {
            //int timeoutSec = 90;
            //cl.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutSec);
            string contentType = "application/json";
            cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));
            cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
            var userAgent = "d-fens HttpClient";
            cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
            return cl;
        }
    }
```

And use:

```
string _tokenUpdated = "TOKEN";
HttpClient _client;
_client.AddTokenToHeader(_tokenUpdated).GetAsync("/api/values")
```

Answer (score 4):

These days, if you are using MS Dependency Injection, it's highly recomended to plug in the IHttpClientFactory:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");

    // using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
    // The GitHub API requires two headers.
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample");
});

var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("GitHub");
```

This way you avoid adding default request headers to a globally shared httpclient and moreover don't have to deal with manual creation of the `HttpRequestMessage`.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consumption-patterns