# HttpClient Headers vs HttpRequestMessage Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, asp.net-web-api2

When should we use headers in the `HttpRequestMessage` object over headers in the `HttpClient`?

We have need to add Authorization (always changing) and few custom headers (always changing).

Questions

1. Which is the preferred method?
2. Should I be adding common
   headers (same across all the requests) to the `HttpClient` and request
   based headers to the `HttpRequestMessage` object?

   ```
      //HttpRequestMessage Code
       HttpRequestMessage reqmsg =new HttpRequestMessage();
       reqmsg.Headers.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("some scheme");
       reqmsg.Headers.Add("name","value");

       //HttpClient Code
       HttpClient client =new HttpClient();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("some scheme");
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("name", "value");
   ```

Comment: Perhaps a nitpick, but the current thinking seems to be to instantiate HttpClient as a singleton, not as a short-lived object (in which case, don't forget to Dispose/use 'using').

Comment: @MaxBarraclough It would seem that the general consensus now is **_not_ to wrap HttpClient in a using block** as it will leak connections instead of just recycling the HttpClient. Please see some of the comments in these SO questions: [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient) and [Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync/40707446#40707446)

Comment: @AnthonyWalsh This article agrees with you: seems my first suggestion was good, but not my second one: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> 1. Which is the preferred method ? Should i be adding common headers (same across all the requests) to the HttpClient
> 2. and request based headers to the HttpRequestMessage object ??

Your questions are auto-answered themselves.

`DefaultRequestHeaders` are ones that will be part of any request, which is a plus because you'll be able to avoid repeating yourself adding some headers one over again. In the other hand, `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` will be only part of that request.

When should you use one over the other? I'm going to use two examples:

- I need to send an OAuth bearer token as part of every request so I set the `Authorization` header in the `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`, and if I need to refresh the token, I just need to set it again there.
- I need to send an entity serialized as JSON or XML depending on some condition. That is, I'll set the `Content-type` header in a per-request basis.

Comment: "and if I need to refresh the token, I just need to set it again there." I don't think changing `DefaultRequestHeaders` is thread safe...

Comment: @Aldracor you are correct in that DefaultRequestHeaders isn't thread safe.  Recommended practice is to use a static instance of HttpClient for the entire app.  Never use DefaultRequestHeaders or BaseAddress, always use HttpRequestMessage.