# How can I add a HTTP Header called "Content-Type" to an HttpClient request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have seen other answers that say you shouldn't do this and Content-Type does not belong on the Request, etc.  Ignoring all of that...

Let's say I'm working on Mars and I need to use HttpClient and have it send the "Content-Type" HTTP header (I am checking in Fiddler).  Is there any way to do this?  I am doing a GET so I am not sending any content.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync

Comment: If you are not sending any content (`GET` request) then you do not need to set the `Content-Type` header. Use the `Accept` header to specify what type of content you want back.

Comment: if the person who wrote the web service is checking for the existence of that header and throwing an error if it's not present, then I DO NEED IT.  stop arguing with the premise of the question.

Comment: The actual solution to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959464/1195056). I'm with Mike where I'm dealing with an external API I'm calling that doesn't follow all the specs for HTTP requests, so the "well you shouldn't do it" is irrelevant.

Comment: I've voted to reopen so that it can be closed with the proper duplicate.