# azure function app parallel execution ,fix httpclient instance duplicate header key issue :An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, httpclient

I'm using **azure function apps(Queue trigger)** to run the hourly jobs. I'm generating a job for each tenant and pushing it to the **Queue => which triggers** the function app.
For each job(class with some logic) I'm passing **APIservice**.
[image]

**APIservice** is an instance of **HttpClient** with baseuri and tenant code will be stored in **header**.As can be seen below

[image]

Lets say if I have 5 tenants , 5 jobs are triggered at once and are executed in parallel. But some times (not always) I'm facing this error.

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderDescriptor
```

I expected each instance to be independently initialized , but sometimes it is giving this error. How do we avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); should take care of it. But it sounds like some connections are still open. Is the connection being disposed of? You could try a using statement that will help with this, or even better is to inject httpClient which is the correct way to do it. See below:

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly string ApiBaseURL;

        public MyController(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpClient = httpClient;

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("H1", _configuration.GetValue<string>("H1"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("H2", _configuration.GetValue<string>("H2"));
            ApiBaseURL = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiBaseURL");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderDescriptor

The Error message shows that you are adding the **same headers** every iteration.

To avoid that you can use the **new**

```cs
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

If you want to add the Authorization headers, you can use like below

```cs
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

Normally, if you are not interested in setting up the header on the `HttpClient` instance by adding it to the `DefaultRequestHeaders`, you can use ***set headers per request*** where you'll be obliged to use the `SendAsync()` method.

To reuse the `HttpClient`, this is the right solution and good practice to:

- Avoid Performance and port exhaustion problems
- Avoid adding the same Headers on each iteration
- Make headers thread-safe.

#### References:

- [Adding Http Headers using sendAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022965/adding-http-headers-to-httpclient)
- [Adding headers and good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707446/15997690)