# How to get a paypal access token using http request?

Tags: http, paypal

I need to integrate my mobile app with paypal. For this I chose Rest API. But I can't get access token! I use Mozilla Firefox just for testing network operations. And here my request

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

Here Header

```
ost: api.sandbox.paypal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/42.0/whatsnew/?oldversion=41.0.2
Content-Length: 172
Origin: https://www.mozilla.org
Connection: keep-alive
```

And here body with params

```
username=AWFcJ...FsdE:EFCK..Dfr43d
grant_type=client_credentials
```

In username I put my Client Id and Secret from dashboard.

Response is

```
400 Bad request. 
error:invalid_client
eror_description:Client credentials are missing
```

What I did wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, the `PayPalConfigDto` contains some basic stuff that you need to provide. Please bear in mind that the values should be stored in the app settings file of your app and this is only a simple example:

```
public class PayPalConfigDto
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

    public string TokenUrl => $"{BaseUrl}/v1/oauth2/token";

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
}
```

The PayPal API response object:

```
public class TokenDto
{
    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public string Access_token { get; set; }

    public string Token_type { get; set; }

    public string App_id { get; set; }

    public string Expires_in { get; set; }

    public string Nonce { get; set; }
}
```

The PayPalContext class:

```
public class PayPalContext
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    private PayPalConfigDto _payPalConfig;

    public PayPalContext(HttpClient httpClient, PayPalConfigDto payPalConfig)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _payPalConfig = payPalConfig;
    }

    public virtual async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var url = $"{_payPalConfig.TokenUrl}?grant_type=client_credentials";
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_payPalConfig.ClientId}:{_payPalConfig.ClientSecret}")));

        var responseTask = _httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
        responseTask.Wait();
        var response = responseTask.Result;

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var errorMessage = response.ToString();
            throw new Exception($"An issue occurred during the trial of getting PayPal token. {errorMessage}");
        }
        var tokenDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenDto>(result);

        return tokenDto.Access_token;
    }

}
```

The `GetToken` method needs to encode the credentials and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628308/9918730)
you can do this quite easily with

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_payPalConfig.ClientId}:{_payPalConfig.ClientSecret}")));
```

To test all the stuff you can just create a simple test class e.g.:

```
//[Ignore]
public class PayPalContextTests
{
    readonly PayPalConfigDto PayPalConfig = new PayPalConfigDto()
    {
        BaseUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com",
        ClientId = "your ClientId",
        ClientSecret = "your ClientSecret"
    };

    [Test]
    public async Task Should_return_valid_token()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();           
        var context = new PayPalContext(httpClient, PayPalConfig);
        var token = await context.GetToken();
        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(token));
    }
}
```

I also think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390393/9918730) can be helpful if you'd like to get a token via Postman, which is a tip to the thing you can find in [the main PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi  you approach is right

try this

```
  public string clientId=<your client id>;
  public string secret=<your secret>;
  public string accessToken='';

  public void accessToken()
  {
      string input=clientId+':'+secret;
      Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(input);
      string paramvalue = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(myBlob);
      Http http=new Http();
      HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
      req.setMethod('POST');
      string endpoint='https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials';
      req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
      req.setHeader('Authorization','Basic '+paramvalue);
      req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
      req.setHeader('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      req.setHeader('Accept-Language','en_US');
      req.setHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
      req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');
      HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
      res = http.send(req);
      if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
      {
           Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
           accessToken = (string)results.get('access_token');
           system.debug(accessToken);
      }



  }
```

Comment: I think it would be awesome if you explain your code a little.

Comment: for this I use basic auth  and in basic auth ,here " input "is concatination of client id and secret and ':' between them,

the Blob.valueof() will convert string to blob and EncodingUtil.base64Encode() will use that value to convert it into a value which is passed a key value with 'Basic' keyword from key "Authorization" as u can see that in code.

please tell me if u got any issue
thnks