# "error": "unsupported_grant_type", "error_description": "Grant Type is NULL" Postman with Paypal

Tags: paypal, postman

I am following the instruction on how to get an access token from Paypal using Postman.

I keep on getting this error message:

> "error": "unsupported_grant_type",   "error_description": "Grant Type
>   is NULL"

Here is my postman setting:

Url: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

Authrization: Username: client_id... Password: secret...

Header: Content-Type -> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

body: form-urlencoded

```
key: grant_type
value: client_credentials
```

Comment: What does your request look like in Postman? Can you post a screenshot, masking out your Auth details obviously.

Comment: Same issue for me but my issue was I had a space at the end of the grant_type key, ie: "grant_type ". After wasting nearly a full day I finally realized.. that's all it was

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the screenshots.
I guess your problem in flow when you insert `grant_type` in body.

[image: Choose "Basic auth" type]

[image: Add body content]

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using Insomnia, here are the settings

[image]

[image]

[image: Add username as client-id and password as secret]

Use Basic Auth to setup username and password

**Enter username as `client-id` and password as `secret`**

Answer (score 0):

check the structure of the body, like below.

```
body: {
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded: [
    {key: "grant_type", value: "openapi_2lo", disabled: false},
]
```