# Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Must provide HTTP header "Authorization" or URL parameter "authorization"

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, dropbox-api

I dev on Dropbox API, using C# universal app.

```
public async Task<string> Httpclient(string link) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response= await client.GetAsync(link);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

public async Task<Model.Get_Current_Account.RootObject> get_current_account(string _accessToken) {
    var query = await mainViewModel.Httpclient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account?access_token="+_accessToken);
    if (query != null) {
        var get_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Get_Current_Account.RootObject>(query);
        return get_data;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

`var query` produces an error:

> Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Must provide HTTP header "Authorization" or URL parameter "authorization"

Answer (score 1):

Reading the dropbox [API docs](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/) suggests you should be passing an authorization header (which matches the error you are receiving)

```
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient) shows how to add headers to HttpClient

Comment: Thanks but It require a "method" is POST.(Method = "get")

Comment: This is correct. Another option, per the error message you posted, is to use an "authorization" URL parameter, instead of the "access_token" URL parameter used in your code.

Comment: Further, the method should be POST, not GET, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HttpClient`, try using an `HttpWebRequest` and set the HTTP header that the API is looking for:

```
public async Task<string> Httpclient(string link, string token)
{
    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add(
            HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, 
            string.concat("Bearer ", token));
        request.Method = "get";
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        else return string.Empty;
    }
    catch { return string.Empty; }
}
```

This should get you headed in the right direction.

You will need to provide `token` data for authorization to be successful.