# Add authorization permanent token header to POST JSON using HttpClient in REST API

Tags: c#, json, post, httpclient, access-token

I am trying to POST a JSON with `HhttpClient` using a permanent token authorization, but I always get an error 401 Unauthorized code:

```
public static async Task<Uri> CrearitemAsync(Item item)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", AuthToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "items/" + IdProvider, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
```

The token seems to be fine. It is an alphanumeric string all lower case. Is this the correct way to use a permanent token?

**update** The key i have to use for the header is: IDENTITY_KEY
but still failing

Comment: Not directly related, but [you are using `HttpClient` wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: Don't serialize item manually (JsonConvert.SerializeObject). Just pass *item* to PostAsJsonAsync. (or use *StringContent* and *JsonConvert.SerializeObject*) to do it manually

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate as Cory pointed out but still I am not sure if this is the correct way to use a permanent token, thanks for the comments

Comment: the header key i have to use is: IDENTITY_KEY
but still error 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it worked with Add.. had to use this 'key' value rather than authorization in the header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("IDENTITY_KEY", AuthToken);
```