# how to issue a post request webclient under specific jwt context

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, jwt, httpclient, dynamics-crm-2015

How can I issue a POST request under the context below using *webclient*?

I am able to successfully authenticate and retrieve a `jwt` token from ADFS:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstXml);
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
    var responseData =
        client.UploadData($"https://{adfsServer}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed", data);
    var rstr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData);
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(rstr);
    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("wsse",
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("wsu",
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
    jwt = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//wsse:BinarySecurityToken", nsmgr).InnerText; // JWT
 }
```

How do I issue a POST request under this same context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the question to which you are referring is for ```HttpClient```, not ```WebClient```

Comment: Well, you just edited out the `HttpClient` part. It's the same, just change the name of the properties

Comment: Curious. why not using HttpClient? Any specific restrictions? Not saying it is impossible, just wanted to know limitations.

Comment: Also a little confused as to the goal. If you have succeeded in attaining a token. What is stopping you from including it in the Authorization header of subsequent calls? Just as you were able to add the content type header when authenticating, you should be able to add an Authorization Header to make authorized requests.

Comment: @Nkosi you are always around to help :) thank you. when you mention ... 
_including it int he Authorization header of subse.._ isnt this exactly what your answer is suggesting to do?

Comment: I added the answer to demonstrate that comment. yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization header should be able to be added to the client to make authorized requests.

```
//Adding authorization token to header
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + jwt);
//Resetting content type to be sent if we wanted to POST JSON
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
//POST json
var json = "{ \"Key\": \"Hello World\" }";
var response = client.UploadString("__url_here__", json);

//...
```