# How to send oauth_token and client_id in the request body of GraphQL Client endpoint in c#

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

Hello friends I want pass `oauth_token` and `client_id` in request body of a GraphQL Client. So how can I pass them, because GraphQLRequest has only three fields (i.e Query , Variables and OperationName). Please suggest.

```
using GraphQL.Client;

var heroRequest = new GraphQLRequest{ Query = Query };
var graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient("URL");

var  graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.PostAsync(heroRequest);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add the **Authorization** (or any other parameter) to the Header using the **DefaultRequestHeaders** from **GraphQLClient**.

```
var graphClient = new GraphQLClient("https://api.github.com/graphql");
graphClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"bearer {ApiKey}");

var request = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = @"query { viewer { login } }"
};

var test = await graphClient.PostAsync(request);
```

Here you can find more detailed information about the DefaultRequestHeaders from HttpClient:
[Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Also, there's a related issue created on graphql-dotnet git.
https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client/issues/32

Comment: If your GraphQLClient is the one from https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client ,
then GraphQLClient class does not have definition for DefaultRequestHeaders.

Comment: Any answers how to add headers in   https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client ?

Comment: var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("http://localhost/graphql", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ????");

Answer (score 4):

Use GraphQL**Http**Client instead of GraphQLClient

example:

```cs
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphQLHttpClient _client;
    
    public DemoController(GraphQLHttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> YourMethod()
    {
        _client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT", yourToken);
        var query = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = "query{......}"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course you have to **register** your GraphQLHttpClient in **Startup**.

Example:

```cs
services.AddScoped(s => new GraphQLHttpClient(Configuration["YourGraphQLUri", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("localhost/graphql", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer()); 
graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ????");
```