# Authorizing AD Group\User With HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kerberos, windows-authentication, unauthorized

I'm getting a 401 error whenever I attempt to get a response from HttpClient when I turn off Anonymous Authentication.

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcUGFycmlzaFxEb2N1bWVudHNcJ0xSXFNvdXJjZVxBcHBzXExSUiBBRkVcTFJSX0FGLVxhcGlcYWZlXDg0QTk0NjVFQzg2QTQwQjNBNEJCNkJDOTI3MTFGRjNB?=
    Cache-Control: private
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 18:14:05 GMT
    Content-Length: 6166
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
```

For testing I have the controller Authenticating on a single user.

```
[Authorize(Users = @"Domain\Username")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string exampleId)
    {
        var baseUrl = $"{Request.Url.Scheme}://{Request.Url.Authority}{Url.Content("~")}";
        var client = new HttpClient(); // <-- This is WRONG*
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}api/example/{exampleId}");
        var example = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExampleModel>();
        return View(example);
    }
}
```

I've looked into using `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authentication`, but I don't see a way to get it to work with ActiveDirectory.  I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient/32691285) but can't understand where I'd be getting an authorization token in this case.

If I create a new controller manually and invoke it directly instead of through the API this works, but it really isn't authenticating anything in that case right?

*Edit:

As [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) points out, my error was not initializing the HttpClient correctly.  Here is how it should have been written:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
```

Comment: please show us how you're using HttpClient. Most likely you'll want to set UseDefaultCredentials = true I think, from memory

Comment: Yep, that worked.  I updated the controller to instatiate the HttpClient with the `HttpClientHandler` and it passed.  I knew I was missing something.  Create this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `UseDefaultCredentials = true` (in an instance of `HttpClientHandler`, which you pass to the `HttpClient`).