# Property or indexer 'AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parameter' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public IList<FormResponse> GetForms(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
       string storeCode = ExtractBasicAuthUserFromHeader(request);
       List<Form> forms = _apiRepository.GetForms(storeCode);     ///23424324  
       return forms;
}

 private string ExtractBasicAuthUserFromHeader(HttpRequestMessage reqeust)
 {
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(reqeust.Headers.Authorization.Parameter 
     ));

      return usernamePassword.Substring(0, usernamePassword.IndexOf(':'));
  }
```

I wrote following test to test above

```
private readonly Mock<IApiRepository> _apiRepository = new Mock<IApiRepository>();


[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
    _apiRepository.Setup(x => x.GetForms("23424324")).Returns(_forms); //skipping FromBase64String converation for understanding
}


 [TestMethod]
 public void GetForms_ReturnFormList()
 {
  HttpRequestMessage reqeust = new HttpRequestMessage(); ;

  //Error   CS0200  Property or indexer 'AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parameter' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only  
reqeust.Headers.Authorization.Parameter = "23424324:12341234123"; 

  IList<FormResponse> formList = _formService.GetForms(reqeust);

  Assert.AreEqual(formList.Count, 2);
 }
```

getting following error

> Error  CS0200  Property or indexer 'AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parameter' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

wondering how can I mock HttpRequestMessage reqeust = new HttpRequestMessage();
to add reqeust.Headers.Authorization.Parameter base string
to test GetForms functionality in services class

Comment: You should set the entire value of `reqeust.Headers.Authorization` as `request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(somesceme, someparameter");`.

Comment: That solve my problem, Did not realize it was that simple :) please add it as answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.Headers.Authorization` is of type `AuthenticationHeaderValue` and this class has properties `Scheme` and `Parameter`. These properties are ready-only.

You are getting error because you are trying to assign value to these ready-only properties.

What you need to do is to assign value to `request.Headers.Authorization` by creating an object of `AuthenticationHeaderValue` class.

Consider doing following.

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(somescheme, someparameter);
```

You need to put actual values in place of `somescheme` and `someparameter` in above code.

You can get details about `HttpRequestMessage` and `AuthenticationHeaderValue` classes at below mentioned links.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
       new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", "=" + value);
```

More here: 
[Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)