# How do I send a POST request with a body that is a string or a character using httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, api, nunit, httpwebrequest

I have a Post call that takes a string GUID "AA0DB615-D4CB-4466-BC23-0E0083002220"
I am using HTTPWebRequest to send request but I am not sure how to add this along with my Post request. Basically I have not found any method inside the HTTPWebRequest to send a Post that is just a string or a character datatype. Is their anything like request.AddBody.

I have also looked at the GetResponseStream. Can I use this to write to the body as a string or character data type and send the call. I am stuck on this any help would be great

Comment: have a look here a question like yours answered: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253696/how-to-pass-header-and-body-value-using-httpwebrequest-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253696/how-to-pass-header-and-body-value-using-httpwebrequest-in-c)

Comment: This is sending the body as a Json. This part I have already done. But how to send as a string when doing a post call

Comment: I dont think so . you can send string when you choose myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample request that sends a plain text GUID in the body using **HttpWebRequest**, You can set the Content type to **"text/plain"** if you want to explicitly state that the content type is plain text :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL GOES HERE");
request.Method = "POST";
var content = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //You should replace this with your GUID
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(content);
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```