# Restsharp Access to this resource is protected Error on Windows Form

Tags: c#, wcf, restsharp

I have this code in C# Windows forms app

```cs
string data = "";
var client = new RestClient("http://server:port/ords/xx_portal_dev/oauth/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "BCSI-CS-8eb7fa809579930b=1");
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "29");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("Host", "server:port");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");            
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic 3244234wfsdf2342234...");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
data = response.Content.ToString();
```

it work fine in WCF Service Method, but i´m working with windows form application and i get error when run this code on a buttom, I don´t know what is happening...

I always get error  Unauthorized "Access to this resource is protected", but in my WCF service it´s working fine!!!

Comment: In which line you get this error?

Comment: So you're getting a 401 error?

Comment: Use a tool like fiddler to examine the requests from your WCF service and you winforms app, and see how they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628308/1390548

have you tried this to validate the encoding is correct?

```
request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
               $"{yourusername}:{yourpwd}")));
```

Comment: Yes my encoding is correct, I have tested the value with the postman client and it works well.

Comment: Postman gives you the option to export c# code for the request that works. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Yes, postman use restsharp api, i have install restsharp API in both clients WindowsForms and WCF Service but this code only work well in WCF Client, I need to know what is hapening with my windows app, because i alway get Unauthorized message

Comment: I meant, export the postman request from postman and copy that code in C# to test.

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippets are working on the client-sides. It is a process of calling the service. But you say that it works well in your WCF service. is it a client application? it should be a server application which creates the WCF service.
Besides, an Unauthorized request usually due to the wrong credential, please check if the below header is valid.

> request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic 3244234wfsdf2342234...");

Finally, How the client calls depend on the configuration of the service. Please post the complete the server configuration, I will try to write you an example of how to call.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hello, i´m testing Rest oracle cloud service, I need to build windows application client to consume the service. In my testing procees i have create both client (win and WCF) only for evaluate oracle service. My code work fine in wcf client, but the same code doesn´t work in windows application. 
The header an encoding is correct because i have test this with my WCF service Client and even work well with the Postman client application.
Do you have any idea what is hapeening?

Comment: Are these two applications running in the same machine?  On the server-side, there might be a difference in handling the request from different machines

Comment: No, both applications run on the same client-side machine.
WCF application lifts an IIS express instance, while the desktop application does not. It is the only difference.

Comment: What do you mean that WCF application lifts an IIS express instance? Also, I could not understand how do you make a successful call to the service in WCF client application. what is your WCF client application? As far as I know, WCF client application call the service usually with a client proxy. but the above invocation is directly sending an HTTP Post Request. This is totally different. Can you call the service properly in a console application?