# Populating javascript / browser popup credential request programatically

Tags: javascript, c#, httpclient, credentials, browser-automation

I'm trying to programmatically access content behind a web app, that requests credentials via a popup.

Using C#'s HttpClient class, is there a way to request a website, get the credential request, populate the credentials, and pass the second request?

I can't get page source on the password popup that shows up. I'm wondering if there isn't really any Javascript for this prompt per se and it's some kind of lower level browser funcationality.

[image]

Comment: I do not recognize the popup dialog. If that site requiring HTTP authentication the browser will automatically present a popup for credentials. In this case [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient) may help you. But in case this is an application level credential popup (presented by e.g. javascript code from the site) you should give additional information to get us to the point.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bootstrap like modal. if you are on desktop open it on chrome and press F12 to get the devtools. from there either look from the source of the modal, or watch the `Network Tab` with `Preserve log`: `On` to check to which url and with what parameters the form is being posted

I hope this is not for brute forcing the app...