# How to get access token from PayPal in MVC

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to get an access token from PayPal.

I have set it up as an application within PayPal, and I can see my client ID and secret

I am assuming I don't want to expose my secret in the javascript front end, so I am attempting to get the access code from the C#, pass the token to the front end so I can make AJAX posts/gets.

However, it always returns with unauthorized

This is my effort

```
var url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

var clientId = "myClientId";
var pwrd = "mySecret";

var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(clientId, pwrd);
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");
var result = "";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
    result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}

return View(model: result);
```

I do not understand why, when I run this from my live application, it fails

**Edit**

I replaced

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
    result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

with

```
var clientId = "myClientId";
var seceret = "mySecret";

var client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
           $"{clientId}:{seceret}")));

 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 dict.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
 var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

The same issue persists. I get a 401

Comment: object httpClient  knows nothing about your credentials/headers.
Use client instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: No, sadly - I've gone that path and the same issues persists @MarkusSafar. Thank you for helping though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it will never authorize, because HttpClient variable knows nothing about your credentials.
You initialized it in WebClient, but you are not using it.

Comment: I don't believe WebClient has `post` - does that mean I'd have to use `UploadString` as the docs show it posts, instead of `DownloadString`?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: it has already an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient
You can use only httpClient for your purposes, or you could also use `UploadString` with webClient. 
But pick one, not both. In your code client knows nothing about httpClient, and vice versa.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should use HttpClient instead of WebClient to get an access token?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: yep, just use credentials in httpClient this time.

Comment: I updated my post - even with the changes you've suggested, the same issue persists :(

Comment: try the same code with sample credentials on: `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/test-and-go-live/sandbox/`

Comment: That returns a Bad Request - slow progress here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240668/discussion-between-bartosz-olchowik-and-mydaftquestions).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comment and other answer, here you create a variable named `client`

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(clientId, pwrd);
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");
```

And in the next code that follows, you do *nothing* using that `client` variable. The above is completely ignored and irrelevant to this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
    result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}

return View(model: result);
```

So, make use of the `client` object you created -- likely with `UploadValues` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for help, I fully understand what I did wrong. But even using `client` still has the same issue of it being unauthorised.

Comment: Nothing anyone can advise without seeing the full response and credentials you're using. You should test in sandbox mode first, not with live against api.paypal.com

Comment: I updated my post - even with the changes you've suggested, the same issue persists :(

Comment: (1) Test with sandbox credentials against api.sandbox.paypal.com , (2) if the problem persists, update your post with both the actual credentials being used, and the actual full text of the HTTP response received, including its debug id

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me :

```
   string bearerToken = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
              $"{clientId}:{secret}"));

   var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
   collection.Add(new("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
   collection.Add(new("ignoreCache", "true"));
   collection.Add(new("return_authn_schemes", "true"));
   collection.Add(new("return_client_metadata", "true"));
   collection.Add(new("return_unconsented_scopes", "true"));

   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}v1/oauth2/token");
       request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {bearerToken}");
       request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
       var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

       JObject jResponse = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
       string accessToken= jResponse["access_token"].ToString();
   }
```