# I am not getting any output and i don't know why

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            YourClient client = new YourClient();
            
            client.Put();
        }

        public class YourClient
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _client;

            public YourClient()
            {
                _client = new HttpClient();
            }

            public async Task Put() // must be async
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/egg"))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
                    request.Content = new StringContent("body", Encoding.UTF8, "content-type");

                    using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var code = response.StatusCode;
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(code));

                        // do something with data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any output and I don't know why. I'm trying to print the response code of the request but nothing is output, is it to do with my method?

I have tried printing hi after `Client.Put()` and it was printed, so I know that my code is actually running, I just don't know why it isn't printing the status code ...

Comment: You are not `await`ing the `Put()` method call and because of that your program just exits before the task is completed and before any output can be written to console. Research [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Answer (score 0):

The excellent comment by Prolog points out *one* of *two* issues. If your Console app is built on **<** C# 7.1 you will need a workaround to prevent the app from exiting (before the request has time to process) so in this case add `Console.ReadKey()` as the very last line. This will spin the message loop until you hit a key. *But this is not the main issue* and I would like to offer a couple of debugging tips.

The **big issue** is this:

- If I run your code, your http request is failing and is throwing a `System.FormatException`
- *Usually* this type of exception is *not* set to **Break when Thrown**. (You can verify this by looking in the Exception Settings window.) Unfortunately, this is giving you a *silent failure* in this case, so you must take matters into your own hands to observe it.

**Suggestions for debugging your code**

1. Use a [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) block around any code that has any likelihood of failing.
2. Use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=net-6.0) which will cause your program to break on a line if any `condition` expression evaluates to `false` (but only when you're running in `Debug` mode not `Release` mode).
3. Add output statements to trace execution. Using `Debug.WriteLine` will send messages to the `Output` window (but again, only in `Debug` mode). Alternatively, since we have a Console app here, I'm using the main app window to output trace statements.

**Example using 1-3:**

```
public async Task Put() // must be async
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin Put()");
    try
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/egg"))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
            request.Content = new StringContent("body", Encoding.UTF8, "content-type");

            using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var code = response.StatusCode;
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(code));

                // do something with data
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(condition: false, message: ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End Put()");
}
```

Now, if I run the code it will break and show what the problem is.

[image: Exception and Assert]

4. Use the Exception Settings window to turn on *all* exceptions (if in doubt). Now the code will break on the exact line that is the problem.

[image: Break when Thrown]

5. Verify that you are [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14627399/5438626) correctly as this may be part of the root cause of the exception.

Finally, if you continue after the `Debug.Assert` you will see the following text in your console which will confirm whether your `Put` method has had a chance to complete or not.

[image: console output]

Hope these suggestions help you solve this problem and future ones!

---

```
// This workaround for C# versions below 7.1 attempts to 
// mimic an `async Main` method. 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunAsync();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async void RunAsync()
{
    YourClient client = new YourClient();
    // Put() should be awaited inside an async method
    await client.Put();
}
```

Comment: I should mention that **I completely agree** with @Prolog that `Put()` _should be awaited_. The problem is if you try and mark `Main` as `async` then it gives you **Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point** error at runtime. So in this particular case we spin-and-wait.

Comment: Since C# 7.1 `Main()` method can be made asynchronous and can return a `Task`, thus you can do `await client.Put()` in the `Main()` method. [Official documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main). Also, [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) when possible.

Comment: **Agree** with your second point also. In C# 7.1 + it should be  `async Task RunAsync()` but you have the option to explicitly discard it with `_ = await RunAsync()` in that case, does that sound right?

Comment: `_ = await RunAsync()` will generate an error since `Task` returned from `RunAsync()` does not return value so there is no value to discard. Have a look at this great introduction to [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Indeed,  I should have said that `_ = RunAsync()` discards the Task and disappears the "Because the call is not awaited..." suggestion whereas `_ = await RunAsync()` discards the _result_ of a Task. Many great changes C# but people like me who are mostly supporting legacy apps (i.e. "more than a day old") have to divide our time and even perhaps pick our battles. Conversations like this one are definitely helpful and I appreciate you providing links to the very latest info. I also edited answer to be more correct in light of.