# HttpClient Unauthorized with Bearer Token

Tags: c#, file-upload, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-401

Due to the fact that HttpWebRequest is obsolete I'm in the process of upgrading to the equivalent in .NET 6.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting a 401 unauthorized. I can get the bearer token successfully but I just can't seem to find the right combination to successfully upload the file.

```
private static async Task UploadCsvFileAsync(string authToken)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://subdomain.domain.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uploadUrl);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.Headers.Add("api-version", "1");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {authToken}");

            string header = $"{Environment.NewLine}--{formBoundary}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csvfile\"; filename=\"{csvFileName}\"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Content-Type: text/csv{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
            byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            var headerContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(headerBytes));
            headerContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(headerContent, "metadata", csvFileName);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(uploadUrl, content);
            // the response code is 401 - Unauthorized
        }
    }
}
```

I have working .NET Framework 4.x code working. Since we're migrating our code to .NET 6 it has to be re-written.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong - I just can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: *03/29/2023 - including correct code as provided by answer below.*

```
private static async Task UploadCsvFileAsyncV2(string authToken)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uploadUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "uploads"))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("api-version", "1");
            string header = $"{Environment.NewLine}--{formBoundary}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csvfile\"; filename=\"{csvFileName}\"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"Content-Type: text/csv{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
            byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            var headerContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(headerBytes));
            headerContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                { headerContent, "metadata", csvFileName }
            };
            request.Content = content;

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

Comment: @Charlieface that's for basic login/password auth. This is bearer token/jwt.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion Don't think you're right about that, the docs seem to indicate that should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-headers-authenticationheadervalue-ctor(system-string-system-string)

Comment: @Charlieface there are different types of authentication methods. "Basic" uses a base64 concatenation of the username and password. "Bearer" just uses the JWT as-is. Yes, using `AuthenticationHeaderValue` is fine but the arguments would still be `"Bearer"` and `authToken`, no additional base64 conversion needed. But the way he has it is fine too and isn't the reason he's getting the 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `HttpClient` quite right. Notice how you declare the `HttpRequestMessage` - where you add the auth header - but never actually use it? You're sort of mixing the old method with the new one and not actually sending out the auth token.

If you want to use `HttpRequestMessage`, which is fine, just use `HttpClient.SendAsync` and supply the message. Specifically try this after `byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);`:

```
      request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
      var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();                  
      content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(headerBytes)), "metadata", csvFileName);
      request.Content = content;
      var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I guess trying so many things I completely missed adding the request.

Can you explain what you mean by, "You're sort of mixing the old method with the new one..." I would like to understand to avoid using the old method.

Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Sure I just mean that it's less common to use `HttpRequestMessage` now, at least that's my impression. `HttpClient` has `PostAsync` and such which scaffold much of the message for you so you don't have to make your own `HttpRequestMessage`. But in your case where you're injecting the headers on your own, that's pretty low level, so you just use `SendAsync` which takes the message rather than the more abstract `PostAsync`, etc., methods. Maybe I should have said you were previously mixing the high level and low level approaches, so instead just stick to low level.