# HTTP Basic Authorization in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, http-headers, http-authentication

Perhaps I'm missing something, or perhaps .NET is missing something (*preferably the former*)

When building an application (*not exclusively ASP.NET, but such is my situation; specifically an ASP.NET hosted WCF DS*) it seems there's no native way to create a [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) object from an [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx), or any similar request/header container,.

Do we always have to roll our own, or is there some magic tucked away in `System.Net.*` or `System.Web.*` with a signature like:

```
NetworkCredential GetAuthorization(HttpRequest request);
```

It's trivial I know, but I would assume something standard to the HTTP architecture would be included in something that is otherwise so encompassing (*.NET*)

So, home-brew string manipulation, or magic method hiding somewhere?

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically want or need a `NetworkCredential`? Why are `User` (and equivalents) not adequate?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that in most forms of ASP.Net (WebForms, MVC, Web API) there's a convenient `User` property that gives you a more fully featured object (usually implementing `IPrincipal` or `IIdentity`) that offers many features that are convenient. What features, specific to `NetworkCredential` are you wanting to use?

Comment: (*I was confused with my last comment*) `NetworkCredential` is not an absolute requirement, but is fitting; even the description mentions Basic, Digest, etc.

Comment: I'm not currently working with WebForms, MVC, or Web API; instead ASP.NET hosting WCF Data Services. I have access to `HttpRequest`, etc., and assumed that there would/should be a way to obtain a generic credentials object (*`NetworkCredential`*) from somewhere given a supplied HTTP Authorization header. There isn't anything specific about `NetworkCredential` that's necessary. I'm just wondering if .NET has provided us some way of obtaining a generic credentials object based on Basic HTTP Authorization, or if I'm stuck rolling my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in; it would be of limited use, since most clients use Kerberos or Digest authentication instead.

However, it's fairly simple to roll your own:

```
static NetworkCredential ParseBasicAuthorizationHeader(string value)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
   {
      return null;
   }
   if (!value.StartsWith("Basic ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
   {
      return null;
   }

   byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(value.Substring(6));
   value = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(data);

   int index = value.IndexOf(':');
   if (index == -1 || index == 0 || index == value.Length - 1) 
   {
      return null;
   }

   return new NetworkCredential(
      value.Substring(0, index),    // Username
      value.Substring(index + 1));  // Password
}
```

Bear in mind that, like all other HTTP headers, the `Authorization` header is completely controlled by the client, and should therefore be treated as untrusted user input.

Comment: Thanks @RichardDeeming; I was afraid of that. Simplicity aside, I'm a bit surprised that there isn't support for Basic floating around .NET. In any case, +1 for bringing `ISO-8859-1` to my attention, I'm using something else (*`ASCII` I think*)

Comment: @Bracketworks: I found the encoding in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7243567/124386); the spec seems to be unclear on this point, but most implementations seem to use `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm going to leave this here a bit longer, in the event someone stumbles in with a magic bullet from .NET, however discussion of this has the answer looking grim (*though in your favor*)