# Maven fails my unit test because of encoding issues

Tags: java, maven, encoding, utf-8, junit

I have an encoding based unit test in my project. The test passes in Eclipse but fails with Maven.

All my files are UTF-8 encoded and I added the 2 following lines in my pom.xml but the test keeps failing:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Here is the interesting part of the test. `Credentials` is a simple bean storing the password as a String with getter/setter (no other code there).

```
AuthentificationHelper helper = new AuthentificationHelper();
// ...
String password = ":&=/?é$£";
String base64Hash = Base64.encodeString(login + ":" + password);
final String authHeader = "Basic " + base64Hash;
// ...
Credentials credentials = helper.credentialsWithBasicAuthentication(request);
assertEquals(password, credentials.getPassword());
```

The `credentialsWithBasicAuthentication` does the reverse operation of what's being done here:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(authHeader);
//...
String credentials = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(hashedCredentials), "UTF-8");
int p = credentials.indexOf(":");
//...
String password = credentials.substring(p + 1).trim();
return new Credentials(login, password);
```

Here is Maven's output:

```
Failed tests: 
   testCredentialsWithBasicAuthentication: expected:<:&=/?[?$?]> but was:<:&=/?[?$?]>
```

(not sure if this is relevent but my log4j appender is also configured to output data in UTF-8)

Any idea what's wrong? (the surprising part being that the console output is not displayed properly either)

### SOLUTION (embarassing)

The `Base64` class I was using was not the one provided by Apache Commons but a random one.

Replacing:

```
import random.bla.bla.Base64;
// ...
String base64Hash = Base64.encodeString(login + ":" + password);
```

by

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
// ...
String base64Hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(new String(login + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

solved the problem.

Cough, cough, tumbleweed.

Comment: There's a lot of missing info here.  What is `credentials.getPassword()`? How is the data traveling from the first block of code to the test? How is the expected value declared and encoded?  This is unanswerable without a lot more detail.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, updated the question a bit but the hidden code doesn't do anything smart about encoding. The relevant bits are here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base64.encodeString(login + ":" + password)` is implicitly using a character encoding (the platform default, which could conceivably be different between Maven and Eclipse), because it has to convert the string to a byte array before it can hash it. You should specify it explicitly - presumably ISO-8859-1, see this question [What encoding should I use for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication).

It's also possible that Eclipse has a different idea of the source file's encoding than Maven (you can check by right clicking the file and doing Properties). Usually m2e sorts that out for you.

An aside - why are you writing code to deal with HTTP authentication? You should use a library.

Comment: As a matter of fact, your answer (and Jim Garrison's comment) helped me realized the Base64 class i was using wasn't Apache's one but one some random class provided by another library my project depends on. I've updated the question with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the workaround is to escape the characters like

```
String password = ":&=/?\u00e9$\u00a3";
```

Comment: thanks, your solution was interesting but i had a preference with the one i've used for readability of the test.