# HTTP Header using non-english character

Tags: rest, http

I am using Advanced REST Client Application (Chrome plugin) to perform authentication using HTTP header and it works.

```
X-Username: member
X-Password: abc123
```

However when I tried to use non english username

```
X-Username: 阿里巴巴
X-Password: abc123
```

I get the following error

```
Unable set request header: X-Username: 阿里巴巴
```

How can I set a request header to use Chinese character if it's possible ?

Comment: By convention it is not allowed to use such characters in a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the specification [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) (HTTP 1.1):

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data.

That said, there is a standard HTTP header for credentials, the `Authorization` one. You can use the basic authentication and its content would be encoded with base64:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

The value after `Basic` is the encoded value of the string `username:password`. For more details about such mechanism, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication.

See also this answer for more details: [What encoding should I use for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry