# Can get response from browser, but 401 unauthorized from resttemplate

Tags: java, rest, http, https, resttemplate

Can get from the response from Chrome, but when I want to get it with resttemplate it gives me 401 response.

I try to add the exact Content Types with rest template but it still gives the 401 error.

here is the request that i get it from Chrome :

```
GET URL HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic auth
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8
```

and here is the code that i used in java to connect the service :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
messageConverters.add(converter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(params,createHeaders(username, password));

restTemplate.getForObject("URL",String.class, entity);

public static HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
    String auth = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", authHeader);
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with encoding the authorization token generation.
If you are sure about the username and password is correct, the only possibility is that the method/encoding used to generate the token is different on the browser(or the UI application which is generating the token) and the implementation of your `createHeaders()` method.

Please refer to the below links for more details:

[What encoding should I use for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication)

https://github.com/request/request/issues/1334

Hope it'll help.

Comment: nope it is not, checked the both token and they are same