# Domino Basic authentication fails when username contains special characters

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have angular application which receives data from domino. In the angular code, i access domino url via basic authentication.

```
URL: apidata.nsf/doLoginSuccessAuth?OpenPage
UserName:Vijay Superuser2ö

Authorization: Basic VmlqYXkgU3VwZXJ1c2VyMsO2OkluaXRQYXNzMjAyMw==
```

[image]

When the username contains the special characters, the authentication is not working. I can login with the same username and password successfully via browser. If i remove the special character, basic authentication works just fine.

I have checked below article and the configuration is done as mentioned in the article.
[https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0082364](https://stackoverflow.com).
I am using Domino 12.0.1.

Do we need to enable any character encoding setting to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your Base64 string using ISO-8859-1 (instead of UTF-8).

So for password "initPass2023" your Base64 string should be "VmlqYXkgU3VwZXJ1c2VyMvY6aW5pdFBhc3MyMDIz" instead of "VmlqYXkgU3VwZXJ1c2VyMsO2OmluaXRQYXNzMjAyMw==".

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik. It works now with ISO-8859-1 encode.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your the Base64 string in your question through a [decoder](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) that produces hex output. I was looking to see how the password decoded. But what I saw instead is that it is decoding like this:

[image: Base64 decoded into hex.]

I stepped through it looking for the colon character that separates the username and password. The colon is hex 3A. The bytes before the 3A are 55 73 65 72 32  - "user2".  The character that should be between the 32 and the 3A ("2:") is completely missing.

Whatever code you are using to construct the Base64 string either has an off-by-one problem that skips the last character of the username, or it doesn't handle the special character at all. Since you're not showing the code, we can't tell which is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I provided wrong base64 earlier. It is edited now properly. The base64 is autogenerated by postman in the above case.

Comment: The special character ö is being encoded as C3 B6, which looks like UTF-8.

Comment: What I would do here is use the builtin debug features of my browser to examine the network transaction for a regular user login and decode the base64 into hex to determine what is being sent and verify whether it is sending 8859-1. I trust Per Henrik's answer, but character sets are a long-standing hobby of mine so I like to verify these things myself.

Comment: Also, the answer to this question confirms 8859-1 as the default, but indicates that you should be able to add an additional header to change that if you need to stick with UTF-8.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Thanks Richard. Long way to go for me to understand about charsets. Interesting area to explore after this issue.

Comment: After 40 years of dealing with charsets, my #1 hint is something that one of my colleagues told me during my first week in the international products group of an old computer company:  Always look at the hex byte values in memory. You can never trust anything else. Good luck!