# Why is HTTPBuilder basic auth not working?

Tags: groovy, basic-authentication, httpbuilder

The following code doesn't authenticate the user (no authentication failure happens, but the call fails due to lack of permissions):

```
def remote = new HTTPBuilder("http://example.com")
remote.auth.basic('username', 'password')
remote.request(POST) { req ->
    uri.path = "/do-something"
    uri.query = ['with': "data"]

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        json ?: [:]
    }
}
```

But the following works fine:

```
def remote = new HTTPBuilder("http://example.com")
remote.request(POST) { req ->
    uri.path = "/do-something"
    uri.query = ['with': "data"]
    headers.'Authorization' = 
                "Basic ${"username:password".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        json ?: [:]
    }
}
```

Why isn't the first one working?

Comment: How does it fail?  The server should return an HTTP 401 status code to trigger the basic authentication.  HttpBuilder will then send a second request with the Authorization header.

Comment: It just doesn't work. The request itself returns with a message saying the user doesn't have permissions to perform the operation. I can change the username and password to something completely invalid and the same thing happens.

Comment: This should potentially solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588256/using-groovy-http-builder-in-preemptive-mode

Answer (score 1):

Two things that I can think of off the top of my head.

The `.setHeaders` method requires a map. Have you tried
 `'Authorization' : "Basic ${"username:password".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()}"` ?

If not, It's a bit more work and code, but you could user the `URIBuilder` as well. Generally I encapsulate to a different class

```
protected final runGetRequest(String endpointPassedIn, RESTClient Client){
      URIBuilder myEndpoint = new URIBuilder(new URI(Client.uri.toString() + endpointPassedIn))
      HttpResponseDecorator unprocessedResponse = Client.get(uri: myEndpoint) as HttpResponseDecorator
      def Response = unprocessedResponse.getData() as LazyMap
      return Response
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server isn't fully HTTPBuilder-compilant. It should return 401 code (which is standart behaviour for REST servers, but non-standart for others) for HTTPBuilder to catch this status and resend authentication request. [Here](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/Authentication#basic-authentication) is written about it.

Comment: It fails also on compliant servers